# Real-world origin of verse - "Ran! Tan! Terre et ciel!"

Tags: history-of, inspiration

In the fantasy series "A Wizard In Rhyme" by Christopher Stasheff, the 2nd book "The Oathbound Wizard" contains the following verse:

> Ran! Tan! Terre et ciel!
>   Terre et ciel, et sang vermeil!
>   Ran! Tan! Earth and sky!
>   Earth and sky, and fire and flood!
>   Ran! Tan! Earth and sky!
>   Scarlet streams of blood!

I know that I've read an expanded version somewhere. Does this poem have a real-world origin? Can someone point me to the full version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The song is a heavy corruption of a tradional "war dance" of the Gauls known as "[Gwin ar c'hallaoued](http://www.musicanet.org/robokopp/french/vivevieu.htm)" (The Wine of the Gauls).

The full text is below:

> Vive le vieux vin de vigne,
>   Le vieux vin gaulois !
>
> Ran ! Tan ! Terre et ciel!  Terre et ciel, et sang vermeil!
>   Tan ! Tan ! Glaive clair,  Flots de sang vermeil !
>
> Mieux que bière ou vin de pommes
>   Mieux vaut vin gaulois !
>
> Ran ! Tan ! Terre et ciel!  Terre et ciel, et sang vermeil!
>   Tan ! Tan ! Glaive clair,  Flots de sang vermeil !
>
> C'est le sang gaulois qui coule,
>   C'est le sang gaulois !
>
> Ran ! Tan ! Terre et ciel!  Terre et ciel, et sang vermeil!
>   Tan !
>   Tan ! Glaive clair,  Flots de sang vermeil !
>
> Sang et vin mêlés ruissèlent
>   Sang et vin gaulois !
>
> Ran ! Tan ! Terre et ciel!  Terre et ciel, et sang vermeil!
>   Tan !
>   Tan ! Glaive clair,  Flots de sang vermeil !
>
> Chant du glaive bleu qui frappe
>   Chant du glaive roi !
>
> Ran ! Tan ! Terre et ciel!  Terre et ciel, et sang vermeil!
>   Tan !
>   Tan ! Glaive clair,  Flots de sang vermeil !

Which roughly translates as;

> Cheers for old wine vine
>   The old Gallic wine!
>
> Ran! Tan! Earth and sky! Earth and sky, and red blood!
>   Tan! Tan! Light sword Streams of crimson blood!
>
> Better than beer or apple wine
>   Better Gallic wine!
>
> Ran! Tan! Earth and sky! Earth and sky, and red blood!
>   Tan! Tan! Light sword Streams of crimson blood!
>
> The Gallic blood flowing,
>   The Gallic blood!
>
> Ran! Tan! Earth and sky! Earth and sky, and red blood!
>   Tan!
>   Tan! Light sword Streams of crimson blood!
>
> Blood and wine mixed rolled down
>   Gallic blood and wine!
>
> Ran! Tan! Earth and sky! Earth and sky, and red blood!
>   Tan!
>   Tan! Light sword Streams of crimson blood!
>
> Song of the blue sword strikes
>   Song of the sword king!
>
> Ran! Tan! Earth and sky! Earth and sky, and red blood!
>   Tan!
>   Tan! Light sword Streams of crimson blood!

A [ran tan](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ran-tan) is described as an onomatopoeic word meaning a knocking, banging, or pounding noise (as of the banging on a drum).